# How to make a onclick function random?

Tags: javascript, css, stylesheet

**Could you guys look at my edited code based on the replies please.**

I have this code right now in my javascript:

```
 function test(sheet)
 {
     document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);
 }
```

And I want to use this function to change my stylesheet

```
onclick="test('CSS/katy.css')"
```

My question is, how do I make the "katy.css" a random css file from my folder.

I was thinking about an array but I don't know how to apply this.

```
var cssName=new Array(3)

cssName[0]="<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='CSS/katy.css'>";
cssName[1]="<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='CSS/daftpunk.css'>";
cssName[2]="<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='CSS/wiliam.css'>";
```

edited button:

```
onclick="test('CSS/' + cssName1[rndIndex])"
```

Edited test function:

```
 function test(sheet)
 {
    var cssName1=new Array(3)

    cssName1[0]="<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='CSS/katy.css'>";
    cssName1[1]="<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='CSS/daftpunk.css'>";
    cssName1[2]="<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='CSS/wiliam.css'>";  
    var rndIndex= Math.floor(Math.random()*3);

     document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating random numbers in Javascript in a specific range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range)

Comment: `onclick="test('CSS/' + cssName1[rndIndex])" ` won't work because you are defining the array and the random index inside of test. So when you pass it to the function, they are not defined yet

Comment: As a matter of fact, since you are doing a random pick, there is no need to pass the array to the function, jsut do everything inside the function, see http://jsfiddle.net/EcBxp/1/

Comment: Hey thanks, the alert does show the a random stylesheet but how do I imply this to the html file so it actually does show the stylesheet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could generate a random int number in [1,3], with the following way:

```
var rndIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
```

Then you can use the generated index to get the css you want:

```
onclick="test(cssName[rndIndex])";
```

**Note** In the cssName table it would be better you place only the corresponding href's. I am saying this, because as I noticed in the declaration of your function you set the value for the href attribute.

**Update** I would suggest, as you will see in the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/C87d3/) to declare a parameterless function for your purpose. I have declared the setCss function and then there select the pagestyele element and set it's attribute called 'href' to one of your css randomnly.

Comment: Double quotes repeating

Comment: I don't think `onclick="test("+cssName[rndIndex]+")";` will run, but `onclick="alert(cssName[rndIndex])"` will

Comment: Hey thanks for reply. I used onclick="test('CSS/' + cssName1[rndIndex])" (is this correct?) And for the test() function I edited it. Could you take a look, cause it ain't working for me.

Comment: @user3406286 you welcome. nope. I think that you have to pass only the href to the test function, as you have declared it. Sure I will take a look right now.

Comment: @ChristosPaisios Please test out your answer, `onclick="test('+cssName[rndIndex]+')";` does not work the way you think it does http://jsfiddle.net/EcBxp/ it's a good thing the OP is not copying the code straight up

Comment: @Huangism yeap I am testing it right now. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @ChristosPaisios post a fiddle please, I think OP will need it

Comment: @Huangism ok will do.

Comment: Thanks guys appreciate the help, but the CSS is in the folder "CSS" how to do I add the location in onclick="test('+cssName[rndIndex]+')";

Comment: @user3406286 you don't need to add it in the onclick, you can just attach it in the test function

Comment: @user3406286 please give me a few minutes and I will come up with a fiddle. Thanks for the patience

Comment: @user3406286 please look here http://jsfiddle.net/C87d3/. In case of having any questions please just let me know.

Comment: Hey thanks it looks great. On the alert it shows a random Stylesheet, but how do I actually make my html file make use of it? Cause now it stays the same stylesheet.

Comment: @user3406286 glad to hear about this. You have to use document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', cssName[rndIndex]); instead of using alert.

Comment: Ah thanks dude really great help! Could I ask one more thing. Is there a way to prevent the code from picking the same stylesheet again? Sorry for asking so much, if you don't wanna answer it's oke, I will mark you as best answer.

Comment: @user3406286 you should mark this one as best answer and do some research, if nothing comes up then post a new queston

Comment: @user3406286 it's nothing too difficult. Try to think about it and do some reasearch. Then if you have any specific question about how to implement it, please post another question or post a comment hear. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Math.random` in a function:

```
var cssName=new Array(3)

cssName[0]="katy.css";
cssName[1]="daftpunk.css";
cssName[2]="wiliam.css"; 

function getRand(array){
    return array[ Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length) ];
}

var static = "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='";

alert(static + getRand(cssName) + "'>");
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/wN5cf/)**

Answer (score 1):

You are in the correct way.

With your array, now you can select a random element as:

```
cssName[parseInt(Math.random() * cssName.length + 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

ok you can use the rand function like the following:

first defined the array

```
var cssName=new Array(3)

cssName[0]="CSS/katy.css";
cssName[1]="CSS/daftpunk.css";
cssName[2]="CSS/wiliam.css";
```

now select the sheet randomlly

```
var index = Math.floor((Math.random()*3));
```

and then select the random sheet

```
onclick = "test("+cssName[index]+")";
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use `Window setTimeout() Method` and for example per 30 second add a new link with jquery .
[setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

And you can see address:
[How to use jQuery setTimeout function](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/02/how-to-use-jquery-settimeout-function.html)

but this idea causes that the speed of your website decreases.

Comment: What is _jaquery_ ? Is _w3schools_ related to an official spec? (answer: no)